Writing & Reading ColumnIndex to Parquet in Rust
Parquet offers a concept of a page index (sometimes also called - column index).
I am trying to write and read Parquet files with page indexes.
parquet crate of Rust is the default choice for working with Parquet files but I didn't find any APIs that allows page index related operations.
I also came across parquet2 library, but unfortunately it has also not implemented indexed pages yet.
How can I go about writing and reading a column index to a Parquet file in Rust? I would like to do it in a way that doesn't violate the Parquet spec.
